# how to add the newline to the toString of the multi-tree

Tags: java, algorithm

There is a structure like this:

```java
public class TreeNode {

private String key;
private List<TreeNode> children;
    ....
```

}

I override the toString() function

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String treeStructure = "TreeNode [key=" + key +  "]";
    if(children!=null){
        for(TreeNode child:children){
        treeStructure = treeStructure+"--- >"+children.toString()+"/n";
        }
    }
    return treeStructure;
}
```

Then I test the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    node.setKey("root");
    List<TreeNode> children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode();
    child1.setKey("child1");
    TreeNode child2 = new TreeNode();
    child2.setKey("child2");
    children.add(child1);
    children.add(child2);
    List<TreeNode> grandchildren = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode grandchild = new TreeNode();
    grandchild.setKey("grandchild");
    grandchildren.add(grandchild);

    node.setChildren(children);
    child1.setChildren(grandchildren);

    System.out.println(node);

}
```

But when I run it the output is:

```
TreeNode [key=root]--->[TreeNode [key=child1]--->[TreeNode [key=grandchild]]/n, TreeNode [key=child2]]/n--->[TreeNode [key=child1]--->[TreeNode [key=grandchild]]/n, TreeNode [key=child2]]/n
```

How can I add the newline in the output like this:

```
TreeNode [key=root]--->TreeNode [key=child1]--->TreeNode [key=grandchild]
                   --->TreeNode [key=child2]
```

But now the child1 showed twice and the newline wasn't added in the result.

================================
I changed the function：

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String treeStructure = "TreeNode [key=" + key +  "]";
    if(children!=null){
        for(TreeNode child:children){
        treeStructure = treeStructure+"\n"+"-->"+children.toString()+"\n";
        }
    }
    return treeStructure;
}
```

then the output is:

```
TreeNode [key=root]
--->[TreeNode [key=child1]
--->[TreeNode [key=grandchild]]
, TreeNode [key=child2]]

--->[TreeNode [key=child1]
--->[TreeNode [key=grandchild]]
, TreeNode [key=child2]]
```

why the child repeated twice and where is the "," from?

Comment: In Java the newline character is "\n" not "/n" as you used.

Comment: see [my answer #print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497119/how-to-save-the-path-of-search-result-in-java-multi-tree/10499759#10499759)

Answer (score 5):

Use `\n` instead of `/n`

```
treeStructure = treeStructure + "--- >" + children.toString() + "\n";
```

Comment: This is because of the `toString()` implementation of List<TreeNode> that you didn't override.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.

Newlines don't belong in *toString()* methods.  They will create quite a mess when someone decides to create a list or map of these objects.  *toString()* should not be a prettyprint.  Use a specific method for that purpose so it can have reliable output.  *toString()* has no such contract to produce formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use \r\n or with BufferedWriter: BufferedWriter.newLine()

The , is written because it is seen like an Array. 
The same reason is for child1 repeated.
Change:

```
treeStructure+"\n"+"-->"+children.toString()+"\n"
```

to:

```
treeStructure+"-->"+child.toString()+"\n"
```